# Generate many files doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to generate several files so I wrote this code where `value` get **797** but I only get one file created, why? should not be 797 files instead? what's wrong in my code?:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = bdCleanList.Count() / Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        string bases_generadas = 
            System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                                   "bases_generadas");

        for (int i = 1; i < value; i++)
        {
            string newFileName = "bases_generadas_" + 
                                 DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + 
                                 ".txt";
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = 
                      System.IO.File.Create(
                         System.IO.Path.Combine(bases_generadas, newFileName)))
            {
                for (byte j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    fs.WriteByte(j);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT** as @andrey-shchekin suggest I added a `i` to `newFileName` so now the code is this one:

```
string newFileName = "bases_generadas_" + i + 
                     DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".txt";
```

But now I run the code again and `value` takes **4** but just 3 files was created:

```
bases_generadas_124-04-2013-11-45-08.txt
bases_generadas_224-04-2013-11-45-08.txt
bases_generadas_324-04-2013-11-45-08.txt
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? does `value` get 797 ? `newFileName` gets new name each iteration ?

Comment: That is because you run from `1` to `<4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Reynier` said, your code can execute within one second and end up creating a single file.

to avoid that you can use, `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()`

```
string newFileName = "bases_generadas_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".txt";
```

or, you can simply use the `i` in the for loop for unique name

```
string newFileName = "bases_generadas_" + 
                     DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + 
                     "-" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is fast enough `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")`  will result in exactly the same file name all 797 times.

Comment: while you are correct I do not think that this is the correct reason why his code doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough, but you did not provide your suggestion.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin are you sure? I don't think so because every time `i` is incremented at least `ss` should take a new value or not?

Comment: @Reynier not necessary, second is long enough. But try adding `i` to your file name and you will see whether that's the problem.

Comment: @Reynier not so, it it is executed in milisecond, then ss will not take a new value.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin and Fendy thanks for your reply and yes you're right the creation of each file occurs in milliseconds so `ss` will not be updated, I'll take a look to see if I can get milliseconds instead of seconds only in `DateTime`